# Any idea why Choosing of attribute sets are disabled in magento 2.0 community edition?

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product, magento-community

Choosing of attribute sets are disabled in magento 2.0 community edition by default while creating configurable product. Any idea why ?﻿

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug. See this post on GitHub.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2567

The work around is to just create a simple product, choose your attribute sets, then when you have combinations / variations it will convert that simple product to a configurable.

Comment: Hi Rudi, You are correct, but how come still Magento 2.0.7 version not solved that issue ?  Also as you said we can create attributes in configuration option of product and add that attributes to attribute sets. But what ever attributes we created separately are also not listed in configure options of attribute lists. Definitely Magento has to take care of this issues.